# How do you run or install starling under RVM?

Tags: ruby, rvm, starling-server

I installed the starling gem under rvm, but there's problem starting starling because it expects permission to write to `/var/spool/starling`, and installing starling under rvm doesn't give it the required permissions. `sudo starling` also doesn't work because it can't find the starling binary. I ended up doing this

```
sudo `which starling`
```

Which works, but I was wondering if RVM had a best practice for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run rvm under sudo.

But you'll have to install all your rubies and gems again or symlink root rvm to your user's rvm folder

```
sudo su
rvm use ruby-1.8.7
gem install starling
...
```